# Capacitor push notification and FCM generate different tokens, crashes android

Tags: android, ionic-framework, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, capacitor

Ionic 5 app with Capacitor push notification and FCM plugins.

```
import { FCM } from '@capacitor-community/fcm';

import {
  ActionPerformed,
  PushNotificationSchema,
  PushNotifications,
  Token,
} from '@capacitor/push-notifications';
```

Why do they both generate different tokens??

For Capacitor/PushNotifications, the following generates a token

```
PushNotifications.addListener('registration',
        async (token: Token) => {
          console.log('token: ' + token.value);
        }
      ).catch(e=>{alert('reqPerm'+e)});
```

While for FCM, the following generates a different token

```
FCM.getToken()
      .then(async (r) => {
         console.log(`token saved ${r.token}`)
        })
      .catch((err) => console.warn('error saving token', err));
```

The FCM token works on iOS (iPhone receives notifications), but registering it on Android, it says something about invalid token registered. So I had to use the token from *PushNotifications.addListener* for Android, but when it receives a notification, the app crashes.

I made sure that the google-services.json file is in the android/apps folder.

What gives?? Any suggestions?

Comment: The token received from `registration` on iOS is the APN token not the FCM.. it is not documented hence easy to get confused. For your crash on Android, can you dump the phone log using logcat.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in new update FCM is returning JWT token. There is a workaround for it same as iOS. you need to register for it before you get token.

```
getToken() {
    PushNotifications.requestPermissions().then(async (permission) => {
        if (permission.receive == "granted") {
            // Register with Apple / Google to receive push via APNS/FCM
            if (Capacitor.getPlatform() == 'ios') {
                await PushNotifications.register();
                PushNotifications.addListener('registration', (token: Token) => {
                    FCM.getToken().then((result) => {
                        console.log(result.token); // This is token for IOS
                    }).catch((err) => console.log('i am Error', err));
                })
            } else if (Capacitor.getPlatform() == 'android') {
                await PushNotifications.register()
                PushNotifications.addListener('registration', async ({ value }) => {
                    let androidToken = value; // this is token for Android use this token
                });
            }
        } else {
            // No permission for push granted
            alert('No Permission for Notifications!')
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: This is the entry in the issue tracking of this bug:
https://github.com/capacitor-community/fcm/issues/99